# fmcomms2 Frontend Interface Redhawk SDR Device

Tags: c++, redhawksdr

I have compiled `"https://github.com/rodrigo455/AD936X_LIBIIO"(Master branch)` in `redhawk ide(Version:2.0.8 and Build id R201801102017)` in Centos 7 after installing `libiio` and `libad9361-iio` as instructed with success. Then I install the device by pick and drop in the Target SDR location in Redhawk perspective and try to launch the device in Sandbox. The Device is launched with logging turned to trace level with the following log output:

**log file:**

```
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:42 - Adding port 'dataShortTX_in'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:46 - Activating port 'dataShortTX_in'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:42 - Adding port 'TX1A_0'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:46 - Activating port 'TX1A_0'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:42 - Adding port 'TX1B_1'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:46 - Activating port 'TX1B_1'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:42 - Adding port 'TX2A_2'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:46 - Activating port 'TX2A_2'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:42 - Adding port 'TX2B_3'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:46 - Activating port 'TX2B_3'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:42 - Adding port 'dataShortRX_out'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PortSupplier_impl:46 - Activating port 'dataShortRX_out'
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE AD936X_LIBIIO_i:87 - virtual void AD936X_LIBIIO_i::construct()
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PropertySet_impl:125 - Setting 0 exec parameters
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PropertySet_impl:143 - Done setting exec parameters
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE Resource:65 - narrow to Registrar object:IOR:000000000000001949444C3A43462F4465766963654D616E616765723A312E30000000000000000100000000000000BC000102000000000E3139322E3136382E3132322E3100B0F10000001D3139333637393336312F060336001F114716100630463814141B484C1B000000000000040000000300000018000000000000000E3230312E3132332E38312E323100B0F10000000300000018000000000000000E3230312E3132332E38312E323100B0F10000000000000008000000004A4143000000000100000024000000000501000100000002000100010001000F00010109000000020501000100010100
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE Resource:85 - Resolve DeviceManager...
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE Resource:89 - Resolving DomainManager from DeviceManager...
2018-09-25 09:26:27 DEBUG Device:1184 - Getting EventManager.... DEV-ID:DCE:601ee5cd-3686-4aeb-a54c-f424c173e600
2018-09-25 09:26:27 DEBUG redhawk::events::Manager:536 - Resolve Device and Domain Managers...
2018-09-25 09:26:27 WARN  redhawk::events::Manager:509 - Resource (DCE:601ee5cd-3686-4aeb-a54c-f424c173e600) does not provide EventChannelManager access, Event channel management is not allowed
2018-09-25 09:26:27 WARN  Device_impl:1195 - Unable to connect to Domain's IDM Channel,  DEV-ID:DCE:601ee5cd-3686-4aeb-a54c-f424c173e600
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PropertySet_impl:164 - Constructor property: fir_filter_control
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PropertySet_impl:164 - Constructor property: target_device
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PropertySet_impl:164 - Constructor property: buffer_size
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PropertySet_impl:164 - Constructor property: FRONTEND::tuner_status
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PropertySet_impl:164 - Constructor property: connectionTable
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PropertySet_impl:164 - Constructor property: receive_chain
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE PropertySet_impl:164 - Constructor property: transmit_chain
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE AD936X_LIBIIO_i:1229 - void AD936X_LIBIIO_i::initAD936x()
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE AD936X_LIBIIO_i:1324 - void AD936X_LIBIIO_i::initAD936x()KAUSHAL IS IN initAD936x() before loadCurrentConfig
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE AD936X_LIBIIO_i:1781 - void AD936X_LIBIIO_i::loadCurrentConfig()KAUSHAL IS IN loadCurrentConfig()
2018-09-25 09:26:27 TRACE AD936X_LIBIIO_i:1787 - void AD936X_LIBIIO_i::loadCurrentConfig()KAUSHAL IS IN loadCurrentConfig() before updateReceiveFrequency
The IDE detected that the process Terminated with exit code SIGSEGV (11)
```

The Device exits with Segmentation fault while in `loadCurrentConfig()` function executing `updateReceiveFrequency()` function. On further probing by putting `LOG_TRACE()` I am seeing during iio_channel_attr_read_double() function execution this behaviour occurs.

Outside Redhawk SDR when I modified ad9361_iiostream.c to determine above mentioned function's behavior it works fine.

Please help with following

1. Why this behavior is observed particularly in redhawk ide

   2. Am I missing something.
   3. The `getContext()` function is modified to connect to ad9361 over network back-end with hard coded IP address(setup is PC(Centos 7
      Linux) to zedboard on which ad9361 fmcomms board is connected).
      4.Will using libiio and libad9361-iio as software package dependencies resolve this issue.
      5.all these functions are present in AD936X_LIBIIO.cpp file in the above mentioned github link.

would be grateful for any help...

Comment: Just a suggestion: You might want to modify the presentation of your question, so that it can be understood and therefore answered.

Comment: done as per your suggestion thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4504896/rodrigo-alencar please provide any inputs ...

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. I'm sorry for the delay

The master branch has a code that was tested using REDHAWK 2.1.3
It is not backwards compatible, since the new code generation modified the base class implementation.

You can try one of the following:

- Regenerate the base class implementation again for your REDHAWK version
- Use the release for [REDHAWK 2.0.6](https://github.com/rodrigo455/AD936X_LIBIIO/releases/tag/v2.0.0)
- Update yor REDHAWK version

Comment: I did use the release for 2.0.6 and was able to proceed. if i hit any roadblocks i will get in touch with you soon...

Comment: If you have project specific problems, I think you should raise issues on the [github project page](https://github.com/rodrigo455/AD936X_LIBIIO/issues), instead of asking questions here. the community might help you though